# Required tags on meta are a little heavy

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, tags, design

The required tags on meta feel a heavy and dark, and they're a little distracting:

[image]

Could we make them have the same background and text color as 'normal' tags, but with a slight border?

[image]

```
color: #535a60;
background-color: #eff0f1;
border: 1px solid grey;
```

Comment: I agree, it seems that other sites [like SO](https://i.imgur.com/BUEqqjd.png) use much lighter background colors.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestions. I agree and I fixed it a little. It's in production now but we probably have to wait till Monday to see it live.